# belongsToMany error in laravel spatie permission?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

My code is working 1 year ago, but now i got an error when i update my composer.
I used laravel package from laravel-spatie.

"spatie/laravel-permission": from `1.16.1` updated to `1.3.0`,

laravel version : laravel 5.2

```
FatalThrowableError in BelongsToMany.php line 599:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in 
/var/www/html/mto-erp/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Traits/HasPermissions.php on line 18
```

**Controller**

```
$user = User::where('partner_id',$id)->first();
$permission = Permission::where('name','LIKE','accounting_%')->select('name')->get();
$permission = $permission->pluck('name')->toArray();
$user->revokePermissionTo($permission);
if(Input::get('permissions')){
   $user->givePermissionTo(Input::get('permissions'));
}
```

laravel permission package - [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-direct-permissions-see-below-to-use-both-roles-and-permissions)

Comment: Try changing `$permission = $permission->pluck('name')->toArray();
` to `$permission = $permission->pluck('name');`

Comment: same error. I think its a package issue.

Comment: show the code for `givePermissionTo()` and `revokePermissionTo()`

Comment: `givePermissionTo`  and revokePermissionTo() are method given by laravel-spatie package. 

[laravel-spatie -here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-direct-permissions-see-below-to-use-both-roles-and-permissions)

Comment: Can you show us your constructor?

Comment: actually my code is working fine before i run `composer install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's something wrong of spatie/permission version 1.3. I also encountered that problem .
Try to install spatie/permission version 1.16* that fixed my problem.

Comment: yeah you right! i downgraded it to `1.16.1` and re-run composer install thats solve my problem.

Comment: Post error-logs to developers webstie? This gives them possibility to fix bugs.